# How to make specific input readonly and take value (0.00) when a specific value exists in another input using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```js
$(document).on('change keyup', '.debtor , .creditor', function() {
  //get amt and qty value
  var debtor = $(this).closest('tr').find('.debtor').val();
  var creditor = $(this).closest('tr').find('.creditor').val();
  if (debtor > 0) {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.creditor').val(0).css("pointer-events", "none", "cursor", "not-allowed");
  } else {}
  if (creditor > 0) {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.debtor').val(0).css("pointer-events", "none", "cursor", "not-allowed");
  } else {}
});
```

```html
<td class="td"><input type="number" class="form-control debtor"></td>
<td class="td"><input type="number" class="form-control creditor"></td>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I am trying to make one of the two inputs take the read-only property automatically and take value (0.00) when the other input has any value entered, and when this value is deleted (i.e. when emptying the field that has a value) the two inputs take the normal position and are open to accepting values, so as soon as I write a value in any one of them it takes The other one is read-only mode and take value (0.00), and the (cursor","not-allowed) property is enabled automatically, and as soon as the value is deleted from the other input , the read-only mode is canceled and the (cursor","not-allowed) property is removed automatically.

Comment: FYI: Corrected the title, it's not JaQuery. Ja Rule didn't create jQuery 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this to achieve the desired behavior....

```
$(document).on('change keyup', (e) => {
if (e.target.classList.contains("debtor")) {
    if (parseInt(e.target.value) > 0) {
        $(".creditor").val(0).css("pointer-events", "none", "cursor", "not-allowed");
    }
} else if (e.target.classList.contains("creditor")) {
    console.log("creditor", e.target.value);
    if (parseInt(e.target.value) > 0) {
        $(".debtor").val(0).css("pointer-events", "none", "cursor", "not-allowed");
    }
}
```

});

Answer (score 2):

Add two `input` event listeners to `debtor` and `creditor` which modify the other corresponding to its value:

```js
$(selector).on('input', function() {
  if (this.value) {
      $(otherSelector).prop('readonly', true);
  } else {
      $(otherSelector).prop('readonly', false);
  }
});
```

This can be shortened as:

```js
$(selector).on('input', function() {
    $(otherSelector).prop('readonly', !!this.value);
});
```

Try it:

```js
$('.debtor').on('input', function() {
    $('.creditor').prop('readonly', !!this.value);
});
$('.creditor').on('input', function() {
    $('.debtor').prop('readonly', !!this.value);
});
```

```css
input:read-only {
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <input type="number" class="form-control debtor">
</div>
<div>
  <input type="number" class="form-control creditor">
</div>
```